# how to give different outputs depends on input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

im trying to give different outputs depends on inputs, but i will get the same output for all inputs.

i tried to remove the "or" operator, and the code will work fine! but when using the "or" operator again, the code wont work the way it should

```
voroodi = input('Enter Something: ')
if voroodi == 'h' or 'H':
    print('hello')
elif voroodi == 'g' or 'G':
    print('Goodbye')
```

i expect to get output of "Hello" when i enter the "H" or "h" as input
and "Goodbye" for "G" "g".

but im just getting hello for any input that i enter!

Comment: `if voroodi.lower() == 'h':`

Comment: or: `if voroodi in ('h', 'H'):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`or` doesn’t work that way.  You must say;

```
if voroodi == 'h' or vortoodi == 'H':
```

`’H’` all by itself is considered `True`. Any non-empty string is considered true, so your original statement is `if voroodi == 'h' or True:` which is always true.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
if voroodi == 'h' or voroodi == 'H':
    print('hello')
elif voroodi == 'g' or voroodi == 'G':
    print('Goodbye')
```

Rakesh solution will also worl\k

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator `in`:

```
voroodi = input('Enter Something: ')
if voroodi in 'hH':
    print('hello')
elif voroodi in 'gG':
    print('Goodbye')
```